# ROS installation:Environment setup:No such a file or directory

Tags: bash, software-installation, bashrc

according to wiki tutorial of ROS installation.

All of the previous steps are ok for me, but when I try to do the part of environment setup.
When I type:

```
echo "source /opt/ros/jade/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

into the Ubuntu terminal.
An error appear:`~bash:source/opt/ros/jade/setup.bash:No such a file or directory`
 but I do find `setup.bash` in the `/opt/ros/jade` file.
Why does this error appear and what can I do to resolve it?

Comment: Close-voters..what's unclear here?

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting the error:

```
-bash: source/opt/ros/jade/setup.bash: No such file or directory
```

then you must have typed:

```
echo "source/opt/ros/jade/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
```

instead of :

```
echo "source /opt/ros/jade/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Notice the <kbd>space</kbd> between `source` and `/opt`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this step is just adding the following code to the end of the bashrc file
source

`source /opt/ros/jade/setup.bash`

So, There is another way to do this by trying the following line in terminal `nano ~/.bashrc` then you will see a bash file in your terminal, the you paste the following line at the bottom of your bashrc file

`source /opt/ros/jade/setup.bash`

Then you need to source bashrc file by `source ~/.bashrc`